# Updating a control while writing LINQ to XML arrray?

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I have this code that successfully writes an XML file from an array using LING to XML.

```
XDocument docXML = new XDocument(
            new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),
            new XElement("recordings",
                from Recording r in GetRecordings(ctrl_inFileDir.Text, wmcTypes,     ctrl_useMCEDir.Checked, ctrl_mceDir.Text)
                select new XElement("Recording",
                       new XElement("oid", r.oid),
                       new XElement("name", r.name),
                       new XElement("channel", r.channel),
                       new XElement("filename",r.filename),
                       new XElement("status",r.status),
                       new XElement("startTime",r.startTime),
                       new XElement("endTime",r.endTime),
                       new XElement("Event",
                           new XElement("OID",r.EventOID),
                           new XElement("Title",r.EventTitle),
                           new XElement("SubTitle",r.EventSubTitle),
                           new XElement("Description",r.EventDescription),
                           new XElement("ChannelOID",r.EventOID),
                           new XElement("StartTime",r.EventStartTime),
                           new XElement("EndTime",r.EventEndTime)))
    )
    );
```

I would like to update a control on my dialog box to update the progress of the xml creation.  Can I do this here?  If so how?

Comment: If you are doing this in a background worker, you can instrument your linq statement.

Answer (score 0):

I dont'think  that you can  achieve  this  with linq  you  should  do something like this

```
namespace WpfApplication4
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
   public partial class MainWindow : Window
   {
    BackgroundWorker _backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker();  
      public MainWindow()
      {
          InitializeComponent();
          _backgroundWorker.DoWork += _backgroundWorker_DoWork;
          _backgroundWorker.ProgressChanged += _backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged;
          _backgroundWorker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;  
         _backgroundWorker.RunWorkerAsync(); 


    }

    void _backgroundWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        var  recordings  = GetRecordings(ctrl_inFileDir.Text, wmcTypes,     ctrl_useMCEDir.Checked, ctrl_mceDir.Text);  
        int recCount =  recordings.Count; 
        int i=0 ;  
        foreach (var recording in recordings )
        {
            XElement  xDoc = new XDocument(new XDeclaration("1.0", "UTF-8", "yes"),new  XElement("Recording",
                   new XElement("oid", r.oid),
                   new XElement("name", r.name),
                   new XElement("channel", r.channel),
                   new XElement("filename",r.filename),
                   new XElement("status",r.status),
                   new XElement("startTime",r.startTime),
                   new XElement("endTime",r.endTime),
                   new XElement("Event",
                       new XElement("OID",r.EventOID),
                       new XElement("Title",r.EventTitle),
                       new XElement("SubTitle",r.EventSubTitle),
                       new XElement("Description",r.EventDescription),
                       new XElement("ChannelOID",r.EventOID),
                       new XElement("StartTime",r.EventStartTime),
                       new XElement("EndTime",r.EventEndTime));
            _backgroundWorker.ReportProgress(i/recCount);


        }
    }

    void _backgroundWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        prgBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;  
    }

}
```

}
Hope  this  Help